# Añadir clases a elementos hermanos del que se hace hover

Tags: jquery, sass, hover

Intento hacer un efecto de dock de macos. Los elementos son las etiquetas contenido; el problema es que no sabría como seleccionar elementos previos y posteriores, estuve intentando con previousElementSibling y nextElementSibling.
Es uno de mis primeros acercamientos a js y jquery.

Les muestro parte de mi código que está en un archivo Sass:

```
.hover2{
        margin: 0px 20px;
        transform: scale(1.8) translateY(-15px);
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .hover1, .hover3{
        margin: 0px 20px;
        transform: scale(1.4) translateY(-10px);
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

Aqui les agrego parte de mi codigo php:

```
<div class="bar-Block">
    <div class="dock">
        <ul class="dockCont" id="dock">
            <a id="finder" class="item" onclick="mostrar()">
            <li>Finder</li>
            <img src="src/views/assets/img/dock/finder.png">
            </a>
            
            <a id="appStore" class="item">
            <li>AppStore</li>
            <img src="src/views/assets/img/dock/appStore.png">
            </a>
            
            <a id="notes" class="item">
            <li>Calendar</li>
            <img src="src/views/assets/img/dock/notes.png">
            </a>
```

Aquí les muestro también una parte del archivo jquery. Esta parte es la que se encarga de agregar la clase hover2 al elemento que esta en foco. hover1 y hover3 son los elementos de la izq y der respectivamente del elemento en foco:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover2');
        let value = document.querySelector('.hover2');

        let prevSibling = value.previousElementSibling;
        let sigSibling = value.nextElementSibling;
        prevSibling.classList.add('hover1');
        sigSibling.classList.add('hover3');
    });
    
    $('.item').on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover2');
        let value = document.querySelector('.hover2');

        let prevSibling = value.previousElementSibling;
        let sigSibling = value.nextElementSibling;
        prevSibling.classList.add('hover1');
        sigSibling.classList.add('hover3');
    });
});
```

Comment: Que es lo que estas tratando de hacer?

Comment: pero el selector ::hover de css hace exactamente eso, elimina el js y en css pone ``.item::hover{ aca va el contenido de tu clase hoverd }``

Comment: Revisa .nextSibling y .previousSibling, pero al parecer estás usando jquery, no sé cómo sean esas 2 con jquery

Answer (score 0):

Usando **Vainilla JS**, y la función para obtener los nodos hermanos que encontré [aquí](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-siblings/) que usa `nextElementSibling` y `previousElementSibling` para obtener los hermanos, tienes el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .red-border {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .blue-border {
            border: 1px solid blue;;
        }
        .pad-10 {
            padding: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="pad-10">
        <div class="pad-10">Uno</div>
        <div class="pad-10" id="selectable">Dos</div>
        <div class="pad-10">Tres</div>
    </main>

    <script>

        let getSiblings = function (e) {
            // for collecting siblings
            let siblings = [];
            // if no parent, return no sibling
            if(!e.parentNode) {
                return siblings;
            }
            // first child of the parent node
            let sibling  = e.parentNode.firstChild;

            // collecting siblings
            while (sibling) {
                if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== e) {
                    siblings.push(sibling);
                }
                sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
            }
            return siblings;
        };


        const selectableContainer = document.querySelector('#selectable');


        const selectableContainerSiblings = getSiblings(selectableContainer);

        selectableContainer.classList.add('blue-border');
        selectableContainerSiblings.forEach(sibling => {
            sibling.classList.add('red-border');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hay 3 clases CSS una para añadir algo de padding, otra que añade un borde rojo y otra que añade un borde azul, el elemento central tiene una id, simplemente lo selecciono y le añado un borde de color. Teniendo ese nodo y con la función `getSiblings()` obtengo los hermanos, los recorro añadiendo a cada uno una clase para colorear el borde.

Comment: Creo que en mi caso no funcionaria, porque el recorrido que se haría con el mouse da como resultado que los elementos pasen de estar en hover a otro valor continuamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover2');
        let value2 = document.querySelector('.hover2');
        let prev = value2.previousElementSibling;
        let next = value2.nextElementSibling;
        prev.classList.toggle('hover1');
        next.classList.toggle('hover3');
    });
    
    $('.item').on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover2');
        let value1 = document.querySelector('.hover1');
        let value3 = document.querySelector('.hover3');
        value1.classList.remove('hover1');
        value3.classList.remove('hover3');
    });
});
```